# A String with an extension and a string without(Regex)

Tags: regex, string

I want to look for a string without an extension, for example if I have:

```
mynameisjeff.jpeg
mynameisjohn.notanextension
mynameisbob
```

In the set of strings middle and bottom is the string I want, but the top is the string I want to ignore.

This is the regex expression I have at the moment:

```
(.+)[^\.]+
```

And it produces the following result and it seems to ignore the not bracket so it matches with

```
mynameisjeff.jpeg
```

which is the string i'm trying to aviod

Comment: How are the computer supposed to know what string is an "extension"? Are you going to maintain the extensions yourself?

Answer (score 0):

This matches anything with no extension: `/^[^.]+$/`

This matches anything with something that looks like an extension: `/^([^.]+)\.(.+)/` and puts the filename in the 1st group and the extension in the 2nd.  You will need a searchable array of extensions that you'll need to test against.

There's a way to do it in one regex, if you really need that, but it gets very long and ugly if you have a lot of extensions.

This is maybe gets you part way:

```
if (/^[^.]+$/.test(filename)) {
    alert(filename+" has no extension");
} else {
    var regex = /^([^.]+)\.(.+)/;
    var matches = regex.exec(filename);
    alert("The file part is "+matches[1]);
    alert("The extension is "+matches[2]);
}
```

Even more:

```
function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

// testFilename returns true if filename does not match a known file type (i.e. has a recognized extension)
function testFilename(filename) {
    var extensions = [ "txt", "html", "foo", "bar" ];

    var foo = false;
    if (/^[^.]+$/.test(filename)) {
        foo = true;
    } else {
        var regex = /^([^.]+)\.(.+)/;
        var matches = regex.exec(filename);
        if (!contains(extensions, matches[2].toLowerCase())) {
            foo = true;
        }
    }
    return foo;
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the problem I found was that when i called method group(0) it would match but the method group(1)  would give me strange thing:

Comment: You needed to mention you wanted groups :D

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by groups, but it sounds like the thing I want! How do I go about getting the groups ? :) UPDATE: I think i understand what you mean but I am actually looking for files without extensions, so the string middle and bottom has no extension and I want to find it whilst skipping string 1 UPDATE 2 : so there is no /^[^.]+$/  expression the can put into group ?

Comment: implementation of array.prototype.contains() is left as an exercise :D

Comment: that looks scary ! thanks for the help regardless, still do not have access to rep :(

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by one single regex by using negative lookahead:

```
^(?!.*\.(jpeg|jpg|ext|you|want|to|exclude)$)
```

(Tested using python)

```
>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\.(jpeg|jpg)$)', "foo")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02216FA0>
(with Match object returned means it matches)

>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\.(jpeg|jpg)$)', "foo.bar")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02224060>
(with Match object returned means it matches)

>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\.(jpeg|jpg)$)', "foo.jpeg.bar")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x02216FA0>
(with Match object returned means it matches)

>>> re.match(r'^(?!.*\.(jpeg|jpg)$)', "foo.jpeg")
>>>
(No Match object returned means it does not match)
```

---

If you want to split the string into "file-part" and "extension", so you can determine by code, or for further processing, it can be done using this regex:

```
^(.*?)(?:\.([^.]*))?$
```

This will treat the part before the last period as "file-part", and part after the last period as "extension".  File part is in group 1 while extension is in group 2

E.g. (test in Python)

```
>>> re.match(r"^(.*?)(?:\.([^.]*))?$", "foo.asdfa.bar").groups()
('foo.asdfa', 'bar')

>>> re.match(r"^(.*?)(?:\.([^.]*))?$", "foo.asdfa.").groups()
('foo.asdfa', '')

>>> re.match(r"^(.*?)(?:\.([^.]*))?$", "foo").groups()
('foo', None)
```